# How to bake chicken with a slight crunch?

Tags: chicken

Lately, I’ve been eating a lot at my favourite local fast casual restaurant. What I keep noticing is that they bake their chicken strips with a very slight burnt crust. This gives a really nice, almost crunchy bite to the chicken.

I’d love to know how to bake the chicken to get it like this.

Comment: You could try using searing it lightly with a blowtorch after you've taken it out of the oven.

Comment: I voted to reopen as the question marked as duplicate is about crispy chicken skin. Here the question is about the chicken strips which has no skin.